# Excel: Finding max value and then stating the name of the value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have one sheet with two columns, one "NAME" column and one "VALUE" column.

[image: Sheet one with NAME and VALUE columns]

In the next sheet, I want to find the max value from the "VALUE" column, but show the name from the "NAME" column.

[image: Sheet two with HIGHEST VALUE NAME column]

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple INDEX/MATCH with MAX will do it:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(MAX(Sheet1!B:B),Sheet1!B:B,0))
```

Make sure your numbers are true numbers and not numbers stored as text.  MAX will ignore the numbers stored as text.

Comment: Thanks, but I get this error message: Tried to add picture. But it says "There's a problem with this formula. Not trying to type a formula? When the first character is an Equal (=) or minus (-) sign, Excel thinks it's a formula"

Comment: @Helmet545 does your local setting require the use of `;` instead of `,` to delimit the parts of the formula?

Comment: Yes, it works now! Thanks, a lot. That's why no formulas I try works...

Comment: @Helmet545 please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.